# Cannot run npm run serve and I already run npm update But still keeping up my error

Tags: vue.js, npm, google-cloud-firestore

When i run npm run serve , this error is keep coming up.

```html
Error: Cannot find module './editor-info/linux'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\node_modules\launch-editor\guess.js
- C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\node_modules\launch-editor\index.js
- C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\launch.js    
- C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\index.js
- C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\node_modules\launch-editor\guess.js:9:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\covidcare-ytu-clinic\\node_modules\\launch-editor\\guess.js',
    'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\covidcare-ytu-clinic\\node_modules\\launch-editor\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\covidcare-ytu-clinic\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-shared-utils\\lib\\launch.js',  
    'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\covidcare-ytu-clinic\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-shared-utils\\index.js',        
    'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\covidcare-ytu-clinic\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-service\\bin\\vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
}
```

I already run `npm update` but this error keep coming up .I am new to vue project and this bugs is breaking my patient....Please someone save me.
here is my package.json
`{ "name": "covidcare-ytu", "version": "0.1.0", "private": true, "scripts": { "serve": "vue-cli-service serve", "build": "vue-cli-service build", "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit", "lint": "vue-cli-service lint" }, "dependencies": { "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.26", "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.22", "axios": "^0.21.4", "chart.js": "^3.5.1", "core-js": "^3.6.5", "es-abstract": "^1.18.6", "firebase": "^9.0.0", "nprogress": "^0.2.0", "primeflex": "^2.0.0", "primeicons": "^4.1.0", "primevue": "^3.7.0", "prismjs": "^1.24.1", "uuid": "^8.3.2", "vue": "^3.2.6", "vue-axios": "^3.3.7", "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0", "vuex": "^4.0.0-0" }, "devDependencies": { "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0", "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1", "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0", "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.13", "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0", "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13", "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0", "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0", "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0", "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0", "eslint": "^6.7.2", "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1", "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0", "prettier": "^2.2.1", "sass": "^1.26.5", "sass-loader": "^8.0.2", "typescript": "~3.9.3", "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0" } }`

Here is babel.config.js

`module.exports = { presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'], }`

Comment: can you share your package.json and your babbel.config.js as well?

Comment: module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
}

Comment: that one is babbel.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then is because somewhere you have libraries that require or have Linux dependencies, I recommend to you create a backup of your package.json and remove "@vue-cli" with this:

```
npm uninstall @vue/cli
```

And then install it again:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Other solution can try is to update your npm with the following:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Then delete the folder "node-modules" to clean all libraries that you have installed on your project and then install with the following:

```
npm install
```

Comment: i already .but when i run npm run serve , still occuring bugs .

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: window 10 pro sir

Comment: Try installing the vue/cli again like I let in my answer

Comment: I got a new error after running npm run serve .
Syntax Error: Error: Failed to load config "plugin:vue/vue3-essential" to extend from.
Referenced from: C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\.eslintrc.js
    at Array.reduceRight (<anonymous>)


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.

Comment: you will need to do the same with vue run "npm uninstall vue" and do install again. is because probably the repository that you are using was created with some libraries for Linux base not for windows, but this new error looks like is more the version.